# Kotlin interfaces exporting to Javascript missing properties

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin

I have a simple interface in Kotlin that looks like this:

```
interface IMyInterface {

var name: String

var description: String }
```

With a build.gradle file like this:

```
 apply plugin: 'java' 
 apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

 sourceCompatibility = 1.8

 repositories {
     mavenCentral() }

 dependencies {
     compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
     compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" }

 compileKotlin2Js {
     kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "umd"
     kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true }
```

The javascript that it exports when I build exports this:

```
  (function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define(['exports', 'kotlin'], factory);
  else if (typeof exports === 'object')
    factory(module.exports, require('kotlin'));
  else {
    if (typeof kotlin === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error("Error loading module 'myModule'. Its dependency 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'myModule'.");
    }
    root['myModule'] = factory(typeof this['myModule'] === 'undefined' ? {} : this['myModule'], kotlin);
  }
}(this, function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  function IMyInterface() {
  }
  IMyInterface.$metadata$ = {
    kind: Kotlin.Kind.INTERFACE,
    simpleName: 'IMyInterface',
    interfaces: []
  };
  _.IMyInterface = IMyInterface;
  Kotlin.defineModule('myModule', _);
  return _;
}));
```

If you notice that the javascript that is exported does not contain any of the properties that my interface defines (name,description are missing).

What I would like to see is an export along the lines like this:

```
  IMyInterface = function ( args ) {

  "use strict";

  var _name =  "";
  Object.defineProperty(this,"name",{

    enumerable: true,
    get: function() { return _name; },

    set: function(value) { _name = value; }

  });

  var _description =  "";
  Object.defineProperty(this,"description",{

    enumerable: true,
    get: function() { return _description; },

    set: function(value) { _description = value; }

  });
```

Also I am using kotlin version 1.1.51

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why can't you create a class that implements this interface and use its instance from JavaScript?

Comment: I am creating an API for both java and javascript.  I want to use Kotlin to export out to both java and javascript and maintain a single code-base. In this API it doesn't implement any of the interfaces.

Comment: Well it implements some of the interfaces but not all.  It sets the standard of what some objects should be like.  I am guessing by your question this is not supported in Kotlin?

Comment: When you write `var x: String` in interface, it does not mean that actual implementation of `x` is provided by Kotlin. It means that any class that implements this interface is expected to provide this implementation. You can't use interfaces this way.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Just knowing it isn't an expected behavior from Kotlin helps me from wondering if I had setup something incorrectly.